# What Does Tor Speed Depend On?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, speed

I am wondering what does the TOR speed depend on. I tried using TOR on 2 different wifi networks. One is 20Mbps and the other is 10Mbps. Both times i got the same speed trough TOR. My question is does TOR provide your with better bandwidth if your internet speed is faster or does everybody get the same speed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A "torified" traffic speed depends on :

- Of course, your WAN connection speed, but also to the number of connections available at the same time - including your OS settings. In Linux/Unix tune your buffers also!
- An exit/entry node speed/latency/load - you better configure your Tor instance to pick a close/fast countries by putting their names in a curlies. Don't forget a `StrictNodes 1` line in your torrc!
- Your CPU single-core speed - yes, Tor's crypto is single-core/thread, sadly. Also a RAM-CPU speed *does* matter by the very same reason
- Ability to do a port forwarding, i.e. `ORPort 443` for example in your torrc **and** make this port reachable from outside. If you're making your Tor a middle node, it's speed improves, checked it myself.